# Juntar várias ArrayList em uma coleção

Tags: java, array, lista

É possivel juntar 3 ArrayList em uma coleção e depois enviar como datasource para um relatório. Ou tem outra forma para se fazer isso?

Tenho 3 ArrayList de 3 objetos, queria as informações dessas listas todas juntas em um relatório.

Metódo que gera o relatório:

```
public void gerarRelatorio(List list, int numeroRelatorio) {

    JasperReport report = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/RelatorioXml.jrxml");
        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                "C:\\relatorios1/RelatorioClientes" + "0000" + numeroRelatorio + ".pdf");
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Código onde passa os valores das 3 listas para uma e envia para o relatório:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
// Possibilita a seleção de vários arquivos
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

// Apresenta a caixa de diálogo
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

//ListaAuxiliar <----------------
List<List> listaAuxiliar = new ArrayList<List>();

// Retorna os arquivos selecionados. Este método retorna vazio se
// o modo de múltipla seleção de arquivos não estiver ativada.
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

for (File argumento : files) {
    System.err.println("Argumentos: " + argumento.getPath());
    caminho = argumento.getPath();
    LeitorXml parser = new LeitorXml();
    LeitorXml1 parser1 = new LeitorXml1();
    LeitorXml2 parser2 = new LeitorXml2();

    try {
        /* List<Cliente> */
        listaContatos = (ArrayList<UnimedGuia>) parser.realizaLeituraXML(caminho);
        listaContatosCabecalho = (ArrayList<UnimedGuiaCabecalho>) parser1.realizaLeituraXML(caminho);
        listaContatosLote = (ArrayList<UnimedGuiaLote>) parser2.realizaLeituraXML(caminho);

        System.out.println("Valores: " + listaContatos);
        System.out.println("Valores1: " + listaContatosCabecalho);
        System.out.println("Valores2: " + listaContatosLote);

        //Adiciona todas as listas  <--------------------
        lista.add(listaContatos);
        lista.add(listaContatosCabecalho);
        lista.add(listaContatosLote);

        listaAuxiliar.add(lista);
        //System.err.println("Lista Auxiliar: "+ listaAuxiliar1);
        System.out.println("Teste Ao Juntar Listas: "+lista);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("O parser não foi configurado corretamente.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Problema ao fazer o parse do arquivo.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("O arquivo não pode ser lido.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//Enviar o relatório
int nRel = 0;
for (List lst : listaAuxiliar) {
    System.out.println("Numero do rel: " + nRel);
    System.out.println("LST: "+lst);
    gerarRelatorio(lst, nRel);

    nRel++;
}
```

[image: Isso]

é o que aparece na Saída, quando dou `System.out.println("LST: "+lst);` e depois quando entra no método para gerar o relatório ele da esse:

[image: ERRO]:

Comment: Pessoal, o debate aqui estava muito extenso e foi [movido para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22922/discussion-on-question-by-diego-augusto-juntar-varias-arraylist-em-uma-colecao). Por favor resolvam as dúvidas lá, e editem a pergunta quando tudo estiver claro. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Entenda os requisitos

Pelas informações disponíveis, não pude compreender como as informações são lidas e como exatamente elas devem ser exibidas.

É um erro comum de programadores tentarem ir mudando o código para chegar a um resultado satisfatório sem ter em mente de forma muito clara qual o objetivo a ser alcançado e como tratar os dados disponíveis para se chegar a este objetivo.

Pelo que posso extrair do contexto, a ideia é algo assim:

> Ler `N` arquivos XML com informações de guias, cada Guia sendo composta por algumas informações básicas, cabeçalho e lote, consolidar essas informações em uma única lista e gerar um relatório.

## Dividindo o processo em passos

O segundo ponto é definir exatamente como você pretende fazer isso. Se o requisito mencionado acima for verdadeiro, você pode pensar nas seguintes tarefas:

1. Mapear cada arquivo XML para um objeto ou lista de objetos de domínio que represente as informações de uma Guia
2. Adicionar todas as informações em uma lista
3. Gerar um relatório a partir da lista

### Mapeando o XML

Sei que já existe um código para isso. Mas é estranho a implementação da pergunta usar 3 diferentes *parsers* que retornam 3 diferentes objetos de domínio (`UnimedGuia`, `UnimedGuiaCabecalho` e `UnimedGuiaLote`).

#### Modelando as classes de domínio

Imagino que as 3 classes mencionadas acima se relacionam de alguma forma.

Posso estar completamente enganado, mas parece que `UnimedGuia` é a entidade "principal" e pode ter um cabeçalho e vários lotes.

Se for este o caso, seria melhor modelar as classes assim:

```
public class UnimedGuia {
    UnimedGuiaCabecalho cabecalho;
    List<UnimedGuiaLote> lotes;
}
```

Caso seja apenas um lote por guia, poderia ser assim:

```
public class UnimedGuia {
    UnimedGuiaCabecalho cabecalho;
    UnimedGuiaLote lote;
}
```

Então no fim você vai precisar apenas de uma lista da classe `UnimedGuia`, pois cada item da lista vai incluir já o respectivo cabeçalho e lote.

Sem esse relacionamento, colocando caba objeto em uma lista diferente, eventualmente sua lógica pode se perder e misturar lotes e cabeçalhos de diferentes guias.

#### Lendo o XML corretamente

O que tem em cada arquivo XML?

Se cada XML tiver apenas uma única guia, então você pode retornar só um objeto simples e não uma lista.

De preferência retorna a guia já com o cabeçalho e o(s) lote(s) conforme mencionado acima na parte de modelagem.

Se tiver várias guias em cada XML, retorne então uma lista de guias, mas evite fazer o parse do aquivo várias vezes para evitar problemas de dados misturados como mencionado mais acima.

### Adicionando objetos a uma lista única

Consolidar listas é fácil, mas também confuso se não tiver as estruturas de dados bem definidas em mente.

Primeiro, claro, precisamos de uma lista principal, mas antes disso o mais importante a definir é:

> Uma lista do que?

Se a resposta por uma lista de guias, então a lista será assim:

```
List<GuiaUnimed> guias = new ArrayList<>();
```

Depois, a cada leitura de uma guia você precisa adicioná-la na lista principal. Se for uma guia simples, use o método `add` da lista.

Exemplo:

```
GuiaUnimed guia = parser.lerGuia(arquivo);
guias.add(guia);
```

Porém, se várias guias forem lidas ao mesmo tempo, **não use o método `add`**, pois este adiciona sempre um item à lista. Para adicionar vários itens ao mesmo tempo, use `addAll`.

Exemplo:

```
List<GuiaUnimed> guiasLidosDoXML = parser.lerGuias(arquivo);
guias.addAll(guiasLidosDoXML);
```

O método `addAll` é equivalente a fazer um laço na lista de guias lidas e adicionar um por um à lista principal.

### Gerando o relatório

Se a ideia é gerar apenas um relatório, então basta passar a lista acima e pronto.

Por outro lado, se for necessário gerar vários relatórios, então você vai precisar mudar a lógica que descrevo nos tópicos acima. Entretanto, dificilmente você vai precisar de uma lista contendo várias listas, pois basta gerar o relatório dentro do laço.

Comment: Antes a estrutura do meu projeto estava mais ou menos dessa forma, porém como o arquivo xml contém muitas tags cabei tendo essa ideia. Porque Usando a API DOM eu usava esse metodo: `NodeList listaContatos = raiz.getElementsByTagName("unimed:demonstrativoAnaliseConta");` Mas dependendo da tag que eu coloco ele não pega todas as informações e pula as tags repetidas, como as tags com os nomes dos beneficiários

Comment: Mas acho que vou deixar o cabeçalho e o lote como objetos, pois eles não se repetem no xml. A unica coisa que se repete é o beneficiário que é preenchido na Classe UnimedGuia

Comment: Se eu tenho 2 objetos e 1 lista, como passar todos eles para o relatório? Eu adiciono tudo em uma única lista?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Se um objeto é único no relatório você não deve passar ele como uma lista no `DataSource`. Passe-o como um parâmetro no mapa de parâmetros.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Estou vendo que você está com algumas dificuldades em várias partes do código. O problema não está exatamente em uma parte específica do código, como as listas, mas inclui um pouco do entendimento conceitual sobre sua tarefa e vai até o funcionamento de relatórios Jasper. Talvez seja melhor resolver o problema em partes. Crie uma pergunta sobre como ler os XMLs corretamente para suas classes com um exemplo de XML e suas classes como estão hoje. Depois de resolvido isso, crie uma outra pergunta sobre como passar esses dados para o relatório.

Comment: Eu ja consigo ler os xml, pegar todos os dados das tags e montar um relatório simples. Porem esse relatório que estou tentando montar no momento é maior e contém mais tags. Uma tag se repete bastante que é a que contém os nomes do beneficiário. As outras tags não se repetem. Resumidamente o que eu queria era o relatório com os dados das 3 tags e não só de 1 tag, que era como eu aprendi a fazer.

Comment: Ainda não tentei passar por parâmetros, mas levando em conta que eu gero 1 relatório para cada xml lido, será que da certo?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto O que você passar como DataSource, neste caso a lista, irá o detalhe do relatório, isto é, os itens que se repetem. O que você passa como parâmetro não gera detalhes, mas pode ser acessado de qualquer lugar do relatório, como na seção de cabeçalho (*header*).